# Control Flow Graph of ETL

Tags: epsilon, model-driven, model-driven-development

Has `Control Flow Graph (CFG)` for `ETL` transformation been developed? 
How can I access it?

Comment: @Dimitris Kolovos would you please help me in this regard?

Comment: I'm not aware of any work in this direction